# Getting the error in react js that "this.props.sumOfPrices is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new in react js and i am getting the following error "**TypeError: this.props.sumOfPrices is not a function**"
I am calling this function in the Course class clicker function using props.
My code is given below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class CourseSles extends Component {
    sumOfPrices(price){
        this.setState({total:this.state.total + price});
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { total:0 };
        this.sumOfPrices=this.sumOfPrices.bind(this);
    }

    render() 
    { 
        var courses=this.props.items.map(
        (item,i)=>{
         return <Course name={item.name} price={item.price} key={i} sumofPrices={this.sumOfPrices} active={item.active}/>
        });
        return(
        <div> 
          <h1>You Can Buy Courses:</h1>
          <div id="courses">
              {courses}
        <p id="total">Toatal: <b>{this.state.total}</b></p>
          </div>
        </div> 
        );
    }
}

class Course extends Component {
    clicker(){
      var active= !this.state.active;
      this.setState({active:active});
      this.props.sumOfPrices(active ? this.props.price : -this.props.price);
    }
    constructor(props) { 
        super(props);
        this.state = { active:false };
        this.clicker=this.clicker.bind(this);
    }
    render() { 
        return ( <div>
            <p onClick={this.clicker}>{this.props.name} <b>{this.props.price}</b></p>
        </div> );
    }
}

export default CourseSles;
```

Comment: `sumOfPrices` ≠ `sumofPrices`

Comment: u have a typo in a property name Of and of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo error. Here is the running code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Course from './Course';

class CourseSles extends Component {

    sumOfPrices(price){
        this.setState({total:this.state.total + price});
    }

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { total:0 };
        this.sumOfPrices=this.sumOfPrices.bind(this);
    }

    render() 
    { 
        var courses=this.props.items.map(
        (item,i)=>{
         return <Course name={item.name} price={item.price} key={i} sumofPrices={this.sumOfPrices} active={item.active}/>
        });
        return(
        <div> 
          <h1>You Can Buy Courses:</h1>
          <div id="courses">
              {courses}
        <p id="total">Toatal: <b>{this.state.total}</b></p>
          </div>
        </div> 
        );
    }
}

class Course extends Component {

 clicker(){
   var active= !this.state.active;
   this.setState({active:active});
   this.props.sumofPrices(active ? this.props.price : -this.props.price);
 }
 constructor(props) { 
     super(props);
     this.state = { active:false };
     this.clicker=this.clicker.bind(this);
 }
 render() { 
     return ( <div>
         <p onClick={this.clicker}>{this.props.name} <b>{this.props.price}</b></p>
     </div> );
 }
}


export default CourseSles;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your sumOfPrices method like:

```
class CourseSles extends Component {
    sumOfPrices  = (price) => {
        this.setState({total:this.state.total + price});
    }
//Rest of Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that sumOfPrices and sumofPrices={this.sumOfPrices} have the capital and small O.This is Typo Error.